# Why is the probability for the signal at 160 in the bromine mass spectrum twice as high as for the signals at 158 and 162?

Tags: mass-spectrometry, isotope

The mass spectrum in Bromine, with the molecules $\ce{^{158}Br2+}$, $\ce{^{160}Br2+}$ and $\ce{^{162}Br2+}$:

[image: Bromine Mass Spectrum]
As you can see, the $\ce{^{160}Br2+}$ is almost double in intensity compared to the $\ce{^{158}Br2+}$ and the $\ce{^{162}Br2+}$ peak.

The book I am reading simply states that this is because

> The probability of two different isotopes occurring in a $\ce{Br2}$ molecule are twice that of the same isotope appearing in a $\ce{Br2}$ molecule.

This is supported by the $\ce{^{160}Br2+}$ peak, formed from the $\ce{^{79}Br}$ and $\ce{^{81}Br}$ isotopes. 
Likewise, $\ce{^{158}Br2+}$ peak is formed from two $\ce{^{79}Br}$ isotopes and $\ce{^{162}Br2+}$ is formed from two $\ce{^{81}Br}$ isotopes.

However, I am confused by the explanation given by the book above. 
Why is the probability of two different isotopes occurring in a $\ce{Br2}$ molecule twice that of the same isotope appearing in a $\ce{Br2}$ molecule?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All possible arrangements of $\ce{Br2}$ molecule:

- $\displaystyle 79 + 79 = 158$
- $\displaystyle \color{red}{79 + 81} = 160$
- $\displaystyle \color{red}{81 + 79} = 160$
- $\displaystyle 81 + 81 = 162$

The amount of $\ce{^{79}Br}$ and $\ce{^{81}Br}$ in nature is roughly the same, thus each permutation is equally probable. There are two arrangements that lead to $160$. While $158$ and $162$ each have only one arrangement. Therefore $160$ is twice as likely to be found compared to other masses.

Comment: Because there are only ever two isotopes of Bromine, the outcome of 160 amu is currently illustrated as more likely than 162 or 158.

Answer (score 8):

A way to understand this that may be familiar is that of the Punnett square from biology, since the two isotopes have nearly 50/50 split in nature.

\begin{array}{c|cc}
              &  \ce{^{79}Br}   &  \ce{^{81}Br}   \\\hline
\ce{^{79}Br}  &  \ce{^{158}Br}  &  \ce{^{160}Br}  \\
\ce{^{81}Br}  &  \ce{^{160}Br}  &  \ce{^{162}Br}  \\
\end{array}

When breeding two hybrids (Aa x Aa), it's twice as likely to get a hybrid (Aa) than to get either homozygote.  Similarly, here you have twice the chance to get a 'hybrid' $\ce{^{160}Br}$ than a particular 'homozygote' $\ce{^{158}Br}$ or $\ce{^{162}Br}$ .

However, I would disagree with the wording of the statement:

> The probability of two different isotopes occurring in a $\ce{Br2}$ molecule are twice that of the same isotope appearing in a $\ce{Br2}$ molecule.

The probability is actually identical of two different isotopes occurring and *any* pair of identical isotopes occurring.  This could be worded better:

> The probability of two different isotopes occurring in a $\ce{Br2}$ molecule are twice that of a particular same isotope appearing in a $\ce{Br2}$ molecule.

Comment: @Mithoron I just thought it might be a good (different) way to visualize it for someone who might be used to seeing this from high school biology, but not used to it in this context.

Comment: I see what you did, well OK, I just wanted to say that this question shouldn't be here at all.

Comment: Your better wording uses some not great english: "of a particular same isotope" just doesn't read well. Better might be "twice that of a particular isotope appearing twice in a $\ce{Br2}$ molecule".